# Laravel5.2 custom array validation

Tags: validation, laravel-5, validationrules

I have the following problem, I added  a costume validation rule with the following code:

```
Validator::extend('valid_map',function($attributes,$value,$parameters){

          return !\DB::table('students')
        ->join('institute_level', 'institute_level.id', '=', 'students.institute_level_id')
        ->where('institute_level_id',$parameters[0])
        ->where('students.id',$value)
        ->first();
        });
```

the problem is that I want to pass in the $parameters[0] some value from an array like this:

```
'levelclasses.*.class.*.student_id' =>
'integer|exist:\App\Student|valid_map:levelclasses.*.level_id'
```

this case work successfully with the rules that came with Laravel, now I want this case to work in my rule. 
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'levelclasses.*.class.*.student_id' =>
'integer|exist:\App\Student|valid_map:['levelclasses.*.level_id']
```

Comment: Is it throwing error ? I missed first apostrophe, try now. updated the answer

Comment: Is their anyway to check how laravel did that ?  it may be useful .

Comment: @Bogdan can you suggest a solution ?